# How to make a row select, highlight specific cells

Tags: c#

How to make a Row select highlight specific Cells and not all the Row in a Grid View. I have explored all the questions on SOF, but there is nothing is available.

Comment: If you have tried any code for something like changing `backcolor` of your gridview and that give you some problem, add them ;).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution !! If you want to control the highlight of a row to a certain range of cells, then you need to control the behavior of the cells in question and make them behave differently when the a row is selected.

YourGridviewInstance.GetCellRange(int topRow,int leftColumn,int buttomRow,inr RightColumn)
in other words
YourGridviewInstance.GetCellRange(YourCurrentRow, The column you want to affect,YourCurrentRow, The Same Column you want to affect)

Answer (score 0):

You need the set the selection mode on the Grid to cell selection.

If you want it to act like a row select but keep a few cells un-highlighted you should use `CellSelect` as the selection mode. Then register on row selection changed and set the `cell.Selected = true;` for the ones you want selected, and false for the rest.

Comment: My application requires that, you select a row and part of the row shouldn't be highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `SelectionMode` property of the Grid to `CellSelect`

[image]